# Export from garageband to audacity

Tags: audio-recording, audio, audacity, garageband

I want to export ALL the audio tracks from [garageband](http://www.apple.com/it/ilife/garageband/) to [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/?lang=en).
I searched on the internet and it is apparently not possible ( [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=UnfjlSJw-a8)  for instance), or better it is possible but one track at time.

It seems so weird that nobody found a workaround or wrote a software which performs this acrion...

So, my questions are:

1. is it possible to export the whole (ALL TRACKS) garageband project to audacity?
2. is it possible to export the whole garageband project to any other multi-track recording software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can't export *directly* to Audacity, you can get pretty close using a workaround. The secret is to **freeze all of your tracks** using Garageband's temporary-rendering feature. Internally, this means that all of your tracks are being rendered, individually, as AIFF files.

You can get to these files by ctrl+clicking the .band file and choosing "View Package Contents." Somewhere in the folder hierarchy is a folder called Freeze Files, which contains the AIFF recordings of your last freeze. Copy these to another folder, and import them into Audacity as separate tracks.

You can also import them into any other audio software that allows AIFF import, which is a pretty common feature.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I haven't used Garageband with any regularity since version 2, and I might be remembering the names or steps slightly incorrectly. If so, please edit the answer to fix the errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm told you can export m4a from Garageband. This should be an ADTS encapsulated AAC stream. You can decode that to PCM (wav files) using [FAAD2](http://www.audiocoding.com/faad2.html) and audacity will import that just fine. Its not lossless but 192 kbit/s AAC is good enough for most purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not clear if you can bulk export all tracks or you have to do it track by track.

Comment: Can't you export it as flat aac at 320kbps at 24bit with 44.1k

Comment: what do you mean?